# Изменение данных в MySQL через php

Tags: php, mysql

Данный код предназначен для локальной работы, используется php5, просьба не давать советы по поводу защиты или того что mysql_query и т.д устарели. Имеется следующий код, который выводит таблицу с названием и количеством товара на складе.

```html
 include "config.php"


<table border="1">

 if(!isset($_GET['category_id'])){
  exit();
 }

 $cid = strip_tags($_GET['category_id']);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_sklad WHERE category_id=$cid";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 echo "<tr><th>Название</th><th>Количество</th>
 ";
 while($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  echo "<tr><td>$line->name</td>  <td>$line->kolvo</td> <td><input type='text' placeholder='потрачено'</input></td> <td><input type='text' placeholder='количество'</input></td> <td><input type='submit' value='изменить'></input>";
 }
```

Планируется сделать вот что, для начала ввести количество товара которое на складе. После того как количество появилось в базе, требуется настроить поле потрачено, т.е, после использования товара пользователь вводит сколько он потратил и от общего количества товара отнимается количество которое потрачено. Собственно вопрос вот в чем: как изменять данные в MySQL через php? Например: на складе 2000г красной краски, потрачено 200г красной краски, пользователь вводит данное число и происходит операция 2000-200=1800, как сделать чтобы в таблице вместо 2000 стало значение 1800.

Разобрался я с обновлением, но тут возникла ошибочка. В таблице сейчас все значения в количестве по 0. Я ввожу новые значения, пишет что данные обновлены, но на самом деле все также по 0. Вот код:

```html
 include "config.php"



 if(isset($_GET["kolvo"])){
  $sql1 = "UPDATE products_sklad SET kolvo='kolvo' WHERE kolvo='kolvo";

  if($sql1){
   echo "Данные успешно добавлены в базу";
  }
  else{
   echo "Возникла ошибка";
  }
 }

<table border="1">
 <form method="GET" action="">
  
   if(!isset($_GET['category_id'])){
    exit();
   }

   $cid = strip_tags($_GET['category_id']);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_sklad WHERE category_id=$cid";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "<tr><th>Название</th><th>Количество</th>
   ";
   while($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>$line->name</td>  <td>$line->kolvo</td> <td><input type='text' placeholder='потрачено' name='trata'></input></td> <td><input type='text' placeholder='количество' name='kolvo'></input></td> <td><input type='submit' value='изменить'></input>";
   }
  
 </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Через `UPDATE` запрос в mysql.

Comment: Да, как сказали выше, обычным update. но есть подводные камни.Если со связью что нибудь будет "не очень" то  браузер может после одного нажатия на кнопку, отправить запрос на сервер дважды и при решении "в лоб" вы вычтите значение два раза. Решается передачей в форму неких уникальных значений и проверкой на сервере не совершали ли операцию с этим id ранее. Но для грамотной реализации этого механизма, все операции списания должны фиксироваться в отдельной таблице, отдельными записями. А текущий "баланс' должен быть расчетной величиной "поступление минус все списания"

Comment: @Mike что за чушь. Если руки не на месте и 3 отправится, а может и зациклится.

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста еще раз вопрос, я обновил

Comment: @SanychGoilo Это не чушь. Браузер отправил запрос на обновление, но из за плохой связи соединение обрывается, хотя сервер уже произвел запись и начал отправлять ответ. Многие браузеры делают при этом повторные попытки соединения. Кроме того пользователь может сам нажать обновить страницу и подтвердить повторную отправку формы, если после записи сервер вдруг отдал просто страницу а не редирект на безопасную точку. Так что защита с помощью уникальный id транзакций, обычно в едином механизме с защитой от CSRF атак общепринятая практика

Comment: @РоманКапустин 1) $_GET["kolvo"] необходимо присвоить переменной 2) Если исходить, что в запросе kolvo это то, что берется из гет, то запрос не имеет смысла, потому что он звучит как "обнови все записи где kolvo = n на n"

Comment: @РоманКапустин запись `kolvo='kolvo'` обозначает что вы ищете и устанавливаете этому полу в качестве значения строку с текстом 'kolvo'. Вам надо: 1. в текст запроса подставлять реальное значение переменной с количеством (не забыв проверить что оно число) 2. в части where надо задать условие по которому отбирается та запись, в которой должна быть произведена замена (например id записи) (его надо передать заранее на клиента в отдельном input и принять при обновлении обратно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не достаточно просто написать

> $sql1 = "UPDATE products_sklad SET kolvo='kolvo' WHERE kolvo='kolvo";

Да и сам запрос странный. Он подходит только, если кол-во уникально и не повторяется. И даже если так, его надо изменить

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE products_sklad SET kolvo={$_GET['kolvo']} WHERE kolvo={$_GET['kolvo']}";
```

Вы не произвели сам запрос в базу, т.е. например:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql1) or die('Ошибка');
echo "Обновлено!";
```